# Why doesn't this interfaces post-up script work?

Tags: networking, 18.04

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces` config:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.2/24
     gateway 192.168.1.1
     post-up echo "script run" > /home/user/ifuptest.txt
```

When I bring the iface down and then up again with `ip link set eth0 down` followed by `ip link set eth0 up` the interface comes up ok, but there is no newly created `ifuptest.txt` text file created in the home directory.

Comment: Because...netplan.

Answer (score 0):

**Improvements to the scripts:**

/etc/network/interfaces :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.1.2/24
 gateway 192.168.1.1
 post-up /bin/myscript.sh
```

/bin/myscript.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "script run" > /home/user/ifuptest.txt
```

make executable:

`chmod +x /bin/myscript.sh`

**Troubleshooting on setting down/up the interface:**

Try this:

```
ip link set dev eth0 down
ip link set dev eth0 up
```

then:

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 up
```

and check the difference in behaviour.

Comment: It still fails. Could it be due to the way I'm bringing the iface up and down with `ip link down/up`?